# jq with multiple inputs from different sources

Tags: shell, jq

How can we mix different input sources when using jq ?
For a specific usecase, I'd like to add some data from a file into a feed that was pipe in stdout.

```
$ echo '[{"a": 1}]' > /tmp/a1
$ echo '[{"a": 2}]' > /tmp/a2
$ jq --slurp '.[0] + .[1]' /tmp/a1 /tmp/a2
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 2
  }
]
$ cat /tmp/a1 | jq --slurp '.[0] + .[1]' /tmp/a2  # Expecting the same result
[
  {
    "a": 2
  }
]
```

As you can see, the last command didn't interpret the piped data.

Right now, I'm forced to save the output from the first operation into a temporary file, so that I can do the jq merging operation, before sending it back to the network. Having a single stream would be much more efficient

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'd like to add some data from a file into a feed that was pipe in stdout.

There are various ways to do this, depending on the shell and also the version of jq you are using.

Assuming your jq supports the --argfile option, you might find that quite congenial:

```
cat /tmp/a1 | jq --argfile a2 /tmp/a2 '. + $a2'
```

Here is another variation that suggests some of the other possibilities:

```
jq -n --argfile a1 <(cat /tmp/a1) --argfile a2 <(cat /tmp/a2) '$a1 + $a2'
```

More interestingly:

```
(cat /tmp/a1 ; cat /tmp/a2) | jq '. + input'
```

You might also wish to consider using the `--slurpfile` option instead of `--argfile`, but note that `--slurpfile` always "slurps" the file.

And finally an approach that should work for every version of jq:

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' <(cat /tmp/a1) /tmp/a2
```

In general, though, it's best to avoid the `-s` option.

### A note on slurping

If you compare the outputs produced by:

```
echo '1 2' |
  jq -s --debug-dump-disasm --debug-trace  '.[0], .[1]'
```

and

```
echo '1 2' |
  jq --debug-dump-disasm --debug-trace  '., input'
```

you'll notice the former has to PUSHK_UNDER to store the entire array `[1,2]`,
whereas the latter program just reads the two inputs separately.

In the first program, the memory for the array cannot be freed until after
all the pointers into it have been processed, whereas in the second program,
the memory for . can be freed after the first RET.

Comment: I tried to read the manpage and search online, but couldn't figure out any way, and you gave me 4 different solutions on the fly. Lovely :)

Comment: Why is it best to avoid using the `-s` option?

Comment: To avoid unnecessary usage of memory.

Comment: Does `-s` use any more memory than `. + input`?

Comment: @chepner - I added a note on slurping.

Comment: @J._B._Rainsberger - Your proposed edit introduces too many complications as --slurpfile ALWAYS slurps the file, but I've added a note about --slurpfile.  Feel free to add a comment about the deprecation.

Comment: Why do you have to `<(cat /tmp/a2)` instead of just passing `/tmp/a2` directly?

Comment: @SOFe - To suggest what can be done if the data does not come from a file.

Comment: Note that the current jq manpage suggests avoiding `--argfile` in favor of `--slurpfile`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, where `cat` forwards its `stdin` followed by `a2`:

```
<GENERATE a1> | cat - /tmp/a2 | jq --slurp '.[0] + .[1]'
```

Or this, which is a *compound statement* passing the results of two separate commands into a pipe:

```
{ <GENERATE a1> ; cat /tmp/a2; } | jq --slurp '.[0] + .[1]'
```

Take care to have spaces beside the curly braces and to have a semi-colon before the final one.

Comment: Or more simply, `<GENERATE a1> | jq --slurp 'add' - /tmp/a2`.

Answer (score 0):

Completing peak's answer, you actually don't need redirections:

`jq -n --argfile a1 /tmp/a1 --argfile a2 /tmp/a2 '$a1 + $a2'`

Comment: The jq document advises "do not use", but instead use `--slurpfile`.