# jq: take piped output and insert into json file

Tags: shell, jq

This seems like a super simple task but I somehow can't figure it out / find an answer online.

I have some piped output in the form of `{"key": "value"}` and I need to insert it into an existing json file along the lines of:

```
{
 "existing_key":"value"
}
```

to get:

```
{
 "existing_key":"value",
 "key": "value"
}
```

How do I do this using jq?

Comment: There are quite a lot of "how do I merge two JSON files with jq?" already in our knowledge base, though granted many are more complex than this case -- it did take some looking to find one that was a perfect fit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You are right, but I was tempted to not close it as it was specifically saying coming from a piped output

Comment: @Inian, ...added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533697/jq-with-multiple-inputs-from-different-sources as a second duplicate to cover that aspect of the question.

Comment: `echo '{...}' | jq -s add - tmp.json`.

Comment: This works 90%, but doesn't completely do it. It outputs the correctly merged json to stdout, but when I try to write it to the same file I read from, I get no change. Command: `echo '{...}' | jq -s add - tmp.json > tmp.json`. Is there no way other than creating a temp file?

Comment: @ilmoi, that's another duplicate, this time of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t

Comment: @ilmoi, ...see in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655338/14122 (with the bugfix I just added as a suggestion in comments; if it didn't have that bug I'd have upvoted it so it wouldn't be at 0).