# JQ append object after specific object

Tags: json, jq

Given following json file.

```
{
  "ver" : "v2.0",
  "date" : "11 Jul 2022 21:28 WIB",
  "disk" : {},
  "network" : {},
  "bench" : {}
}
```

I want to append an object after `date`, so the resulting file will be like this.

```
{
  "ver" : "v2.0",
  "date" : "11 Jul 2022 21:28 WIB",
  "hw": {
    "cpu": "intel"
   },
  "disk" : {},
  "network" : {},
  "bench" : {}
}
```

I found this snippet [`jq -S '. |= . + {"hw":{ "cpu" : "intel" }}'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686719) that will append before last object, I tried to modify it a bit but I get `jq: error (at main.json:7): Cannot index object with number`.

Can anyone provide me correct query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in [they's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686734), the ordering of keys don't matter to the reading application

> An object is an unsorted collection of keys. The ordering of keys really should not matter to an application reading the JSON document. If you want ordered data, then consider using arrays instead.

But for some reason, if the ordering needs to be guaranteed, you can achieve the same this way

```
to_entries | 
( map(.key == "date") | index(true) ) as $pos | 
.[0:$pos+1] + [{"key":"hw","value":{"cpu":"intel"}}] + .[$pos+1:] |
from_entries
```

The idea is to convert the JSON records into k/v pairs, find the position of the key named `"date"` and then use slice expressions to append the required object after the position and then append back the rest of the pairs.

[demo - jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/j1FOTbSPLnY)

---

To pass the JSON as a variable, use the `--argjson` flag

```bash
jq --argjson n '{"hw":{"cpu":"intel"}}' '
to_entries |
( map(.key == "date") | index(true) ) as $pos |
.[0:$pos+1] + ($n|to_entries) + .[$pos+1:] |
from_entries' json
```

Or if the JSON text is stored in a file, e.g. `json_file`, use the `--slurpfile` option

```bash
jq --slurpfile n json_file '
to_entries |
( map(.key == "date") | index(true) ) as $pos |
.[0:$pos+1] + ($n[0]|to_entries) + .[$pos+1:] |
from_entries' json
```

If the content is passed over from standard input, use `/dev/stdin` as your input file. Can be used with heredocs as well.

```bash
echo '{"hw":{"cpu":"intel"}}' |
jq --slurpfile n /dev/stdin '
to_entries |
( map(.key == "date") | index(true) ) as $pos |
.[0:$pos+1] + ($n[0]|to_entries) + .[$pos+1:] |
from_entries' json
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great, but what if I want to insert from stdin ? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534029/12289283) but at specific position.

Comment: Currently I get this `jq: error (at <stdin>:7): array ([{"key":"be...) and object ({"server_in...) cannot be added` when replacing `[{"key":"hw","value":{"cpu":"intel"}}]` with variable defined from `--argfile`.

Comment: @Liso Answer updated to pass JSON text as a variable content and from a text file

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother you again, but I need little help, I currently make jq read from pipe by using this `cat file.json | jq --argjson n "$(cat)" 'to_entries | ( map(.key == "date") | index(true) ) as $pos | .[0:$pos+1] + ($n|to_entries) + .[$pos+1:] | from_entries' res.json`. As you can see I'm using `--argjson n "$(cat)"` to feed jq from from stdin, is there any builtin way ?

Comment: and `file.json` is just an example, the actual situation is I'm writing json code using heredoc `cat <<EOF`.

Comment: @Liso See update